# How to integrate cryptocurrency payments in react native ios app (Algorand)

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, algorand

I am using Algorand blockchain for NFT transaction on mobile app. The app is in react native and on the app I am selling/buying NFT's. Apple rejected my app saying that I need to implement in-app purchases. How would I go about doing that?
How to implement a cryptocurrency payment gateway? Does apple's in-app purchases support cryptocurrency payments?

I can't find any helpful resource to resolve this issue.

Comment: No. Apple handles payment for you when you use in app purchase; this could be payment via credit card or apple gift card or PayPal, depending how the user has set up their App Store account. You don’t need to know. You simply receive the funds in your nominated bank account, minus Apple’s commission.  It is not possible to deliver non-physical goods and services in an app using anything other than Apple’s in app purchase.

Comment: Can you explain the process that would follow? How would the transaction between crypto and fiat currency would occur? My app is a marketplace for NFT's. So if one user uploads their NFT for some amount of cryptocurrency and some other user wants to buy it, will they buy it from their crypto or fiat currency?

Comment: They cannot pay with crypto.  They would pay with regular money billed to a credit card or Apple gift card.  If you need to pay the uploader in crypto currency then you would need to acquire that in order to make the payment.  Of course you probably wouldn't want to do that until the funds were cleared from Apple into your account; a process that can take a month or more.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion really helped clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's in-app purchases do not support cryptocurrency payments.

However, they do support cryptocurrency cards that are linked to Apple Pay. Lots of these exist, e.g. Coinbase. There are also rumours that AlgoFi may release one too.

The payment is converted into fiat before the transaction, so on your app it would be like handling a fiat payment. You can then theoretically use this fiat to buy $ALGO, and then use that for the transaction. The UX would ultimately look the same for the end user and it would seem like they are using the existing cryptocurrency in their wallet. But like a commenter said this is not reliable.

Apple does not allow apps that have any payments outside of their payment system. This means that currently an app cannot write to the blockchain at ALL unless payments and gas are relayed. You can work around this by developing an NFT marketplace app that allows users to view their NFTs and explore others, but if they want to do any transactions they are redirected to the mobile website.

So you have three options: trusting that the fiat is successfully taken out of the user's account and buying $ALGO, waiting for the payment to go through which means the transaction may take weeks, or directing to a website for all blockchain transactions.